# count a multiple set of string that all appeared in one line

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

**here is the C# line of code that tries to find the matching string in a line using regex in a textfile**

```
 MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(readedLine, @"/funcdesc=cls/ && /jobcat=VSO/");
countedChars = collection.Count;
```

**This is the sample textfile content**

```
2016-01-01 d;D;;D;funcdesc=cls&workcode=file&jobcat=VSO&jobcat=DSO;

2016-01-02 d;D;;D;funcdesc=cls&workcode=file&jobcat=DSO&jobcat=DSO;
```

expected total count output should be **1**

(because line 1 meet the requirement where both "funcdesc=cls" and "jobcat=VSO" are there, however line 2 did not because there is no "jobcat=VSO" found only the first string.

Comment: Is `&&` valid in a Regex?  I've never seen that before....

Comment: just saw in one stackoverflow answer, i also tried "(funcdesc=cls)(jobcat=VSO)"

Comment: Will they be in that order? If they will, you can use `funcdesc=cls.+jobcat=VSO`, if you only read one line at a time. BTW, remember the past participle of "read" is "read", and not "readed". Also bear in mind that the `/` are only to identify a regex in Javascript, they are not part of the regex expression itself.

Comment: Off the top of my head, something like this might work:  `/funcdesc=cls.+jobcat=VSO` might work.  The `.+` says one or more characters.   I haven't tried it though - there are number of Regex testing sites out there you can use to play around with Regexes.

Comment: i just copies the variable "readed" from somewhere, sorry did not changed it

Comment: what do you mean will they be in that order? funcdesc always coming first?

Comment: He means will funcdesc always be before jobcat in the lines.  If that's not the case, then the Regex will need to be changed.

Comment: they can interchange sometimes

Comment: Use `@"(?=.*\bfuncdesc=cls\b)(?=.*\bjobcat=VSO\b")"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the order of the "funcdesc=cls" and "jobcat=VSO" aren't fixed (i.e., "funcdesc" can come after "jobcat"), you can use the following Regex to capture a match for either case.  There may be more efficient ways to do it, this is just off the top of my head:

```
/funcdesc=cls.+jobcat=VSO|jobcat=VSO.+funcdesc=cls/
```

The `|` is a way to say "OR" in Regex, i.e., either "funcdesc=cls" followed by one or more (`.+`) characters followed by "jobcat=VSO", *or* "jobcat=VSO" followed by one or more characters followed by "funcdesc=cls".

This will match the following:

```
2016-01-01 d;D;;D;funcdesc=cls&workcode=file&jobcat=VSO&jobcat=DSO;
```

or

```
2016-01-01 d;D;;D;jobcat=VSO&workcode=file&funcdesc=cls&jobcat=DSO;
```

but will *not* match

```
2016-01-02 d;D;;D;funcdesc=cls&workcode=file&jobcat=DSO&jobcat=DSO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right pattern would be `funcdesc=cls.*jobcat=VSO` 
Also `$` in regex means end of line.